# Exception when directory does not exist

Tags: symfony, phpcs, php-cs-fixer, symfony-finder

The issue is that if watching multiple directories via the Finder class.
If one does not exist, the Finder will throw an exception and the fixer will die.

```
$finder = Finder::create()
    ->in([
        __DIR__ . '/web/app/mu-plugins/ys-*',
        __DIR__ . '/web/app/plugins/ys-*'
    ])
    ->name('*.php')
    ->ignoreDotFiles(true)
    ->ignoreVCS(true);
```

[image]

Is there a possibility of adding an option to "skip if directory does not exist" so it doesn't kill the fixer if one of the directories does not exist?

Comment: There is no option to do that, you need to check (with array_filter for example) that directories exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use an array_filter beforehand with a simple [glob()](https://www.php.net/glob) function to check if the directories/files actually do exist. Glob will return an array of files/folders if any are found.

If directories/files do exist, pass them to the Finder:

```
$directories = [
    __DIR__ . '/web/app/mu-plugins/ys-*',
    __DIR__ . '/web/app/plugins/ys-*'
];

$checkDirs = array_filter($directories, static function ($dir){
    return !empty(glob($dir));
});

$finder = Finder::create()
->in($checkDirs)
->name('*.php')
->ignoreDotFiles(true)
->ignoreVCS(true);
```